# SharePoint 2013 Setup error

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation

I download Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013, I tray to install it,

first I install all prerequisite file, done

[image]

but when I tray to install SharePoint I have this error

> setup cannot continue because a required file is either corrupted or not available "

[image]

any idea or help please ?

Answer (score -1):

Solved

Corrupted Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013

Then, after downloading the Microsoft Sharepoint 2013 SP product from MVLS. When try the installation, an error occurs (file is corrupted). I did a search. Answer was the need to download the product with the tools offer.

i tray 2 way, but same result (file is corrupted).

so I download the product from another source, and it works very well.

since the last time i do not know if this is a problem in the MVLS or product props make (Downloadable).

Comment: Can you please add more details regarding this, was the downloaded file corrupt?